# How to add different content for different modals vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want to have some buttons opening modals with different content. But when I click them, the same content appears. How do I link them properly? (I have never asked in here so forgive me if I did any mistakes)

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');
const btnsOpenModal = document.querySelectorAll('.show-modal');
const openModal = function () {
  modal.classList.remove('hidden');
  overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
};

const closeModal = function () {
  modal.classList.add('hidden');
  overlay.classList.add('hidden');
};

for (let i = 0; i < btnsOpenModal.length; i++)
btnsOpenModal[i].addEventListener('click', openModal);
btnCloseModal.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
overlay.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="show-modal">Show modal 1</button>
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 2</button>
    <div class="modal hidden">
      <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
      <p>Content1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="modal hidden">
    <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
    <p>Content2</p>
  </div>
    <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
```

Comment: to avoid repeating, change the contents of the modal with js instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the program what modal to open. For this, you need to make each model unique, for this, you can use IDs, or Indexes, depending on the specific case. Also, if your HTML contains multiple elements of the same class, you should use querySelectorAll() most of the times, since it returns an array of all the elements, unlike querySelector(), which only selects the first found element.

```js
const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const btnsCloseModal = document.querySelectorAll('.close-modal');
const btnsOpenModal = document.querySelectorAll('.show-modal');

function openModal(i) {
  closeModal()
  modals[i].classList.remove('hidden');
  overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
};

function closeModal() {
  for (let i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
    modals[i].classList.add('hidden');
  }
  overlay.classList.add('hidden');
};
for (let i = 0; i < btnsOpenModal.length; i++) {
  btnsOpenModal[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    openModal(i)
  }, false);
}
for (let i = 0; i < btnsCloseModal.length; i++) {
  btnsCloseModal[i].addEventListener('click', closeModal, false);
}
overlay.addEventListener('click', closeModal, false);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  background: #0007;
  z-index: 5;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  background: #eee;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="show-modal">Show modal 1</button>
<button class="show-modal">Show modal 2</button>
<div class="modal hidden">
    <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
    <p>Content1</p>
</div>
<div class="modal hidden">
    <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
    <p>Content2</p>
</div>
<div class="overlay hidden"></div>
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much! It fixed it just like I wanted it.

Comment: @daniel You are welcome! Also notice how I used a callback `()=>{}` arrow function in the `addEventListener` function for `openModal()`. It's because you can't pass parameters to `addEventListener`'s callback, but you can bypass it like this.

Comment: @daniel I just saw Andy's answer below. And I think his method is more suitable in most cases. It's more DRY and maintainable to have a ready to use universal component, the content of which you can change via datasets and objects. But anyway, in large scale projects you're going to use JS frameworks 99% of times. There, you'll have native <slot /> or <outlet /> components that are similar to Andy's approach under the hood, but way easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment `querySelector('.modal')` is only picking up one modal, and you have no way of identifying which button relates to what modal.

*Generally* you have *one* modal, and then update the modal content with JavaScript. So that's what this example does. It has one modal, and the buttons are identified by a data attribute. Further: the content you want to update is stored in an object.

When a button is clicked (see [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)) we get the data attribute value, grab the content from the object, update the modal content, and then show the modal.

```js
// Cache the elements - one modal, one close-modal
// button, a button container, and the paragraph in the modal
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const para = modal.querySelector('.modal-content p')
const close = document.querySelector('.close-modal');
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');

// Add one event listener to the button container to 
// catch events from its child elements (the buttons),
// and one to the close-modal button
buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
close.addEventListener('click', handleClose);

// Content
const modalContent = {
  one: "This is the first modal content",
  two: "This is the second modal content"
};

// When the button container catches an event...
function handleClick(e) {

  // We check that it's from a button...
  if (e.target.matches('.show-modal')) {

    // ...destructure the id from the button's dataset...
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;

    // ...use it to get the content from the object...
    const content = modalContent[id];

    // ...and add the content to the paragraph element
    para.textContent = content;

    // Finally we show the modal
    modal.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}

function handleClose() {
  modal.classList.add('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin: 1.5em;
  border: 2px solid #343434;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; z-index: 999; 
}

.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.close-modal {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="show-modal" data-id="one">
    Show modal 1
  </button>
  <button class="show-modal" data-id="two">
    Show modal 2
  </button>
</div>

<div class="modal hidden">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional information

- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: I like this approach better than mine. But to be fair I use Vue a lot and there with components, slots and props this is not a problem ;D. Also if your buttons to open a modal are all over the website and not clustered like here, you should probably use `querySelectorAll('.show-modal')`, loop through the array and add event listeners to each node.